# how to round off if the value is 1.01 to 1, if 1.1 then 2 in java?

Tags: java, rounding

In java

How to roundoff a value(either float, bigdecimal or double) having the following pattern,

(1) If the value is 1.0, i.e., if the decimal is started with zero then this should not rounded off and the value should be the whole number. ie., in this case "1".

(2) If the value is 1.1 i.e., if the decimal place started with number greater than 0, then the whole number should be rounded to the next number. i.e., if 1.1 then it should be 2.

Comment: You may want to extend `BigDecimal` and override its `round` method. Might be some work though.

Comment: To be clear, are these base-ten numbers you are talking about? And _why_ do you want to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So you want to round anything below 0.1 down to 0 and 0.1 or more to 1.0

```
 long round = Math.round(x + 0.4);
```

Comment: Hi Peter! :-) That should be x + 0.4

Comment: You typed faster than I did on my cell phone, but at least I got it right.  :-)

Comment: @user949300 Math.round(double) returns a `long`  ;)

Comment: True.  Putting in the `(int)` is left as an exercise for the IDE.  :-)

Comment: Is there a reason why this isn't using `int round = Math.ceil(x);` ? is round() and arithmetic faster than ceil? Edit: I misread the original post, I see that if the number is 1.01 then it would round to 1 instead of ceiling. My bad.

Comment: @Dbeazy you can write `Math.ceil(x - 0.1)` however 1.1 would round to 1.0

Answer (score 1):

Try this for a start (for float and double)

`int rounded = Math.round(x + 0.4);`

Answer (score 1):

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html. I believe `RoundingMode.CEILING` is what you want. `BigDecimal` lets you control the rounding:

```
new BigDecimal(1.0).setScale(0, RoundingMode.CEILING).doubleValue(); => 1.0
new BigDecimal(1.1).setScale(0, RoundingMode.CEILING).doubleValue(); => 2.0
```

Guava includes some utility classes for rounding floats and doubles directly with `RoundingMode`s.

```
DoubleMath.roundToInt(1.0, RoundingMode.CEILING); => 1
DoubleMath.roundToInt(1.1, RoundingMode.CEILING); => 2
```

Edit: Whoops. I missed the part where rounding `1.01` should result in `1`. The other suggested methods are more correct.

Comment: Are you sure `1.01` would be rounded down as the OP asks?

Answer (score 0):

Your specification is not entirely clear to me. I understand your question to mean the "ceil" function, that is, 1.01 has to be rounded up, but your question can also be interpreted such that 1.01 has to be rounded down. (If the latter is what you want, look at Peter Lawrey's answer.)

For `double`s (and `float`s) Java provides the standard method `Math.ceil(double a)` for the ceil function.

For `BigDecimal` values you can use the `setScale` method: set the scale to 0 (no decimal fraction) and the rounding mode to `RoundingMode.CEILING` to specify how to round:

```
static BigDecimal ceil(BigDecimal a) {
    return a.setScale(0, RoundingMode.CEILING);
}
```